# How to display data in multiple columns with php?

Tags: php, mysql, html, algorithm, loops

Hi I need to build a table with two columns from a mySQL table.
Here is what i have now:

```
<table>
<?php
$sql = "SELECT field1, field2 FROM tblX" 
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die("\nError Retrieving Records.");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array ($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){?>
<tr>
   <td>
       <?=$row['field1']?> - <?=$row['field2']?>
   </td>
</tr>
<?php }?>
</table>
```

This will create one column table like so:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

I need the table to be in two columns like this:

```
1  4
2  5
3
```

Is this possible if it is how do I do that?

Comment: Did you try to add another <td></td> pair in the <tr></tr> accordingly?

Comment: These question is unclear. You didnt mention, what the dump result over that two tables, each. How can anyone determine the argument, to divide that datas into two column?

Comment: Because it is only one table. If I know how I would not be asking here...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do what you want, if you insist on a table.

Get the mid point:

```
$mid = ceil(mysql_num_rows($result)/2);
```

Get an array:

```
while( $row = mysql_fetch_row($result) ) {
    $list[] = $row; }
```

Output the rows:

```
for( $i = 0; $i < $mid; $i++ ) {
    $itemOne = $list[$i];
    $itemTwo = $list[$i + $mid]; 
    // echo them in two tds.
}
```

I agree with marco, though. You could just as easily list items one to $mid in one div, then $mid to the end in another, and use CSS to float the divs side-by-side. Using tables for formatting purposes is evil.

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what i needed.<br/>Developers should not use tables for layout, but tables are there for a reason. IMHO if you want to display table data the best way to do it is in a table.

Answer (score 1):

read all values in a list, get the half value, write a loop that shows [i] and [i+halfvalue] together

Comment: how do you suggest to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear, but it sounds like you want to rearrange how the data is displayed and don't want the standard row-by-row output. You should probably do this manually if your order requires a method that cannot be looped through.

You should arrange the table BEFORE you output it, then once you've got everything all tidy, simply output the code.

Comment: I do not know how to make it more clear than that... How do you suggest to arrange dynamic data? I do not think you understand dynamic data and table... Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Must it be in tables? 
If you have in it a div and you have it set so that 3 items can contain in the height.

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div> 
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
</div>

#container { height: 300px; }
.item { height: 100px; }

You can use some css floating to solve that combined with some padding and margin.
```

Comment: Why does it have to be in `table` tags? If you're wrapping data into columns like this, this probably isn't tabular data from a semantic point of view. If you can do this with CSS, it's more accessible.

Comment: Some data is better displayed in tables... Marko's solution is not good if I am to display more/less then 5 elements(he is using fixed height).

Comment: The height could be set dynamic. Server or client-based.